# The sidebar does not expand to the bottom

Tags: html, css, sidebar, fill, expand

Where is problem and how can resolve it?

I dont want to delete or change any css codes like float and display.

inliner_content used for set side bar to be in line of content.

I use wrap class to have a sticky footer.

I use some customed class and simaulate table structure for DIVs in forms.

Also, this code is a sample code and a series of it has been repeated.

```css
.wrap
{
direction: rtl;
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#menu_icon_mng
{    display: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: url(pics/menu_icon.gif) center;
    background-size: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.main_m_mng
{
    /* height: 14%; */
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    /*      display: inline-block; */
    /*     float: right; */
    padding-right: 10px;
    /*     text-align: center; */
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.main_m_mng_name
{
    /* height: 14%; */
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    /*      display: inline-block; */
    /*     float: right; */
    padding-right: 10px;
    /*     text-align: center; */
    /*transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;*/
    /*cursor:pointer;*/
}
.main_m_mng i
{
    margin-left: 15px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 25px;
    /*     display: inline-block; */
    /*     color:white; */
}
.main_m_mng:hover
{
    background-color: #e0dddd;
    padding: 0 20px 0;
    margin: 0 1px 0;
    /*     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px; */
}

/* .main_m_mng:after {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    content: '';
} */

.sub_menu_mng {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: none;
}

.inliner_content {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 77%;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* display: table; */
    /* padding-bottom: 8px; */
    /* margin-bottom: -19px; */
}

.main_m_link_mng {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    width: 100%;
}
.tbl_frm {
    display: block;
}

.tbl_tr {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.tbl_td {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 150px;
}

.tbl_thead {
    display: block;
}

.tbl_th {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
}
.footer {
    /* position: relative; */
    height: 150px;
    /* margin-top: -150px; */
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
   
    background-size: 116px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="inliner_content">

    
<div class="shadow_main_mnu_mng" style="
    display: none;
    /* direction: rtl; */
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
    /* min-height: inherit; */
    /* height: 100%; */
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
    background-color: #8a4747;
    float: right;
    /* display: flex; */
    margin-top: 82.7%;
    /* margin-right: -150; */
    /* z-index: 100; */
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    /* margin-bottom: 1px; */
"></div>

<div style="min-height: 100%;height: inherit;/* padding-bottom: inherit; */width: 20%;position: absolute;/* clear: both; */min-width: 150px;max-width: 150px;background-color: #bbb2b2;float: right;/* display: flex; *//* bottom: -62px; *//* flex-direction: column; *//* margin-top: 0; *//* margin-top: -256px; *//* margin-bottom: 40px; */z-index: 100;" class="main_menu_mng">

        <div class="main_m_mng_name">Jack Hue     </div>

        <a href="#" id="menu_icon_mng" onclick="f_menu()" onblur="f_menu()"></a>
        <div class="main_menu_list_mng" id="main_menu_list_mng" style="display: block;">

            <a class="main_m_link_mng" href=".mpnt=nzmnd">
                <div class="main_m_mng">
                    <i class="fa fa-volume-control-phone"></i>Account Setting
                </div>
            </a>
            <a class="main_m_link_mng" href="new/mpnt=nzmnd">
                <div class="main_m_mng">
                    <i class="fa fa-volume-control-phone"></i>Posts
                </div>
            </a>

            <a class="main_m_link_mng" href="?pmodir=2646&amp;mpnt=nzmnd"><div class="main_m_mng">
                    <i class="fa fa-volume-control-phone"></i>Users</div></a>


            <a class="main_m_link_mng">
                <div class="main_m_mng"><i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i>Admin Users
                </div>
            </a>
            <!-- <div style="position: absolute;z-index: 105;"> -->
            <div id="sub_menu_mng" class="w3-animate-top-menu sub_menu_mng">
                <div><a href="#">sub menu long</a></div>
                <div><a href="?mpnt=test">User Register</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">Sub menu3</a></div>
            </div>
            <!-- </div> -->

            <a class="main_m_link_mng">
                <div class="main_m_mng"><i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i>New Admin
                </div>
            </a>
            <!-- <div style="position: absolute;z-index: 105;"> -->
            <div id="sub_menu_mng" class="w3-animate-top-menu sub_menu_mng">
     <div><a href="#">sub menu long</a></div>
     <div><a href="?mpnt=test">User Register</a></div>
     <div><a href="#">Sub menu3</a></div>
            </div>
            <!-- </div> -->


            <div class="main_m_mng"><a class="main_m_link_mng"><i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i> Admin Users old link</a>
                <div style="position: absolute;z-index: 105;">
                    <div id="sub_menu_mng" class="w3-animate-top-menu sub_menu_mng">
       <div><a href="#">sub menu long</a></div>
       <div><a href="?mpnt=test">User Register</a></div>
       <div><a href="#">Sub menu3</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div style="
    /* float: left; */
    /* display: inline-block; */
    /* width: 73%; */
    padding: 0 10px;
    padding-right: 160px;
    /* margin-right: -150px; */
    background-color: blue;
    /* z-index: -4; */
    top: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
" class="content">
        
<script src="ref/cml_chk.js"></script>
<script src="ref/statlist2.js"></script>
<!--<script src="chk_frm_reg.js" ></script>-->
<input type="hidden" class="prov1" value="6">

<form name="frmreg" method="post" onreset="" onsubmit="return display_err1()" style="
    margin-block-end: 0em;
">

    <input type="hidden" name="pr_reg_form" value="139">


        


            <input type="hidden" name="pr_reg_form" value="139">

            <div style="margin-right:15px">

                <div class="tbl_tr">
                                            <div class="tbl_td">Date (Today):</div>
                                        <div class="tbl_td" align="right"> :::::::   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        <div id="pers_info">
            <div width="100%" border="0" dir="rtl" cellspacing="10px" style="margin-right:15px" class="tbl">
                <div class="tbl_thead">
                <div class="tbl_th" colspan="3">Pers Info
                    <hr>
                    <br></div>
                </div>
                <!--////////////////////////////////////////================================Form main===========================================================================================================/////////////////-->

            <div class="tbl_tr">
                        <div class="tbl_td" width="">Name :</div>
                        <div class="tbl_td" colspan="2"><input name="fname" id="form_text" type="text" onkeypress="return checkContentname(event)" value=""></div>
                    </div> 
                                    <div class="tbl_tr">
                        <div class="tbl_td">Last Name :</div>
                        <div class="tbl_td" colspan="2"><input name="lname" id="form_text" type="text" onkeypress="return checkContentname(event)" value=""></div>
                    </div>

                

                <div class="tbl_tr">
                    <div class="tbl_td" width="">ID :</div>

                    <div class="tbl_td">
                        <input style="margin-left: 50px" onchange="tel_err2()" name="cmli" id="form_text" type="text" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return checknum(event)" onblur="/*check2()*/" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--//===================================================================================-->
                <!--//===================================================================================-->
                <!--//===================================================================================-->
                <!--        if(){-->
                <div class="tbl_tr" style="display: none">
                    <div class="tbl_td">none disp :</div>
                    <div class="tbl_td" colspan="2" title="">
                        <div>
                            <select name="prov" class="province"></select>
                            <select name="city" class="city"></select>

                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--////////////////////////////////////////================================Form main===========================================================================================================/////////////////-->

            <div class="tbl_tr">
                        <div class="tbl_td" width="">Name :</div>
                        <div class="tbl_td" colspan="2"><input name="fname" id="form_text" type="text" onkeypress="return checkContentname(event)" value=""></div>
                    </div> 
                                    <div class="tbl_tr">
                        <div class="tbl_td">Last Name :</div>
                        <div class="tbl_td" colspan="2"><input name="lname" id="form_text" type="text" onkeypress="return checkContentname(event)" value=""></div>
                    </div>

                

                <div class="tbl_tr">
                    <div class="tbl_td" width="">ID :</div>

                    <div class="tbl_td">
                        <input style="margin-left: 50px" onchange="tel_err2()" name="cmli" id="form_text" type="text" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return checknum(event)" onblur="/*check2()*/" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--//===================================================================================-->                <!--////////////////////////////////////////================================Form main===========================================================================================================/////////////////-->

            <div class="tbl_tr">
                        <div class="tbl_td" width="">Name :</div>
                        <div class="tbl_td" colspan="2"><input name="fname" id="form_text" type="text" onkeypress="return checkContentname(event)" value=""></div>
                    </div> 
                                    <div class="tbl_tr">
                        <div class="tbl_td">Last Name :</div>
                        <div class="tbl_td" colspan="2"><input name="lname" id="form_text" type="text" onkeypress="return checkContentname(event)" value=""></div>
                    </div>

                

                <div class="tbl_tr">
                    <div class="tbl_td" width="">ID :</div>

                    <div class="tbl_td">
                        <input style="margin-left: 50px" onchange="tel_err2()" name="cmli" id="form_text" type="text" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return checknum(event)" onblur="/*check2()*/" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--//===================================================================================-->                <!--////////////////////////////////////////================================Form main===========================================================================================================/////////////////-->

            <div class="tbl_tr">
                        <div class="tbl_td" width="">Name :</div>
                        <div class="tbl_td" colspan="2"><input name="fname" id="form_text" type="text" onkeypress="return checkContentname(event)" value=""></div>
                    </div> 
                                    <div class="tbl_tr">
                        <div class="tbl_td">Last Name :</div>
                        <div class="tbl_td" colspan="2"><input name="lname" id="form_text" type="text" onkeypress="return checkContentname(event)" value=""></div>
                    </div>

                

                <div class="tbl_tr">
                    <div class="tbl_td" width="">ID :</div>

                    <div class="tbl_td">
                        <input style="margin-left: 50px" onchange="tel_err2()" name="cmli" id="form_text" type="text" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return checknum(event)" onblur="/*check2()*/" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--//===================================================================================-->
                </div>



                <!--//===================================================================================-->
                <!--//===================================================================================-->
                <!--//===================================================================================-->

                <!--        -->
                <!--        //================================================================================-->
                <!--        //================================================================================-->
                <!--        //================================================================================-->


            </div>
      </div>
      
<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text



<br>
<br>
</form>    


</div>

</div>

    <div class="spacer_ftr" style="height: 150px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    footer
</div>
```

**I use clearfix, display: table and display: table-cell tricks but dosent work**

Answer (score 4):

By adding `position: relative;` to the `body` element the sidebar fully expands.

Your `.main_menu_mng` have a `position: absolute;` but none of its ancestors is positioned, so your element is positioned relative to the root element (or Initial Containing Block), and from W3C:

> The containing block in which the root element lives is a rectangle called the initial containing block. **For continuous media, it has the dimensions of the viewport** and is anchored at the canvas origin; it is the page area for paged media. The 'direction' property of the initial containing block is the same as for the root element.

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details

So, without a parent with a relative position, the height of your element depends on the height of the root element, which is the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

There is much to improve in your code and different better approaches, but based on your question and your comment to my first answer, I tried to solve what you need with your code.

You could add `position: relative;` to `.inliner_content` (in this case it would stop at the footer spacer).

If you add the following CSS to your `.content` div also the blue form part expands until the footer spacer.

```
.content {
   position: absolute;
   width: 80%;
}
```

Here you find an example where I added everything I just described to your code.

```css
.wrap
{
direction: rtl;
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#menu_icon_mng
{    display: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: url(pics/menu_icon.gif) center;
    background-size: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.main_m_mng
{
    /* height: 14%; */
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    /*      display: inline-block; */
    /*     float: right; */
    padding-right: 10px;
    /*     text-align: center; */
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.main_m_mng_name
{
    /* height: 14%; */
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    /*      display: inline-block; */
    /*     float: right; */
    padding-right: 10px;
    /*     text-align: center; */
    /*transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;*/
    /*cursor:pointer;*/
}
.main_m_mng i
{
    margin-left: 15px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 25px;
    /*     display: inline-block; */
    /*     color:white; */
}
.main_m_mng:hover
{
    background-color: #e0dddd;
    padding: 0 20px 0;
    margin: 0 1px 0;
    /*     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px; */
}

/* .main_m_mng:after {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    content: '';
} */

.sub_menu_mng {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: none;
}

.inliner_content {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 77%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
    /* display: table; */
    /* padding-bottom: 8px; */
    /* margin-bottom: -19px; */
}

.main_m_link_mng {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    width: 100%;
}
.tbl_frm {
    display: block;
}

.tbl_tr {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.tbl_td {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 150px;
}

.tbl_thead {
    display: block;
}

.tbl_th {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
}
.footer {
    /* position: relative; */
    height: 150px;
    /* margin-top: -150px; */
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
   
    background-size: 116px;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="inliner_content">

    
<div class="shadow_main_mnu_mng" style="
    display: none;
    /* direction: rtl; */
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
    /* min-height: inherit; */
    /* height: 100%; */
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
    background-color: #8a4747;
    float: right;
    /* display: flex; */
    margin-top: 82.7%;
    /* margin-right: -150; */
    /* z-index: 100; */
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    /* margin-bottom: 1px; */
"></div>

<div style="min-height: 100%;height: inherit;/* padding-bottom: inherit; */width: 20%;position: absolute;/* clear: both; */min-width: 150px;max-width: 150px;background-color: #bbb2b2;float: right;/* display: flex; *//* bottom: -62px; *//* flex-direction: column; *//* margin-top: 0; *//* margin-top: -256px; *//* margin-bottom: 40px; */z-index: 100;" class="main_menu_mng">

        <div class="main_m_mng_name">Jack Hue     </div>

        <a href="#" id="menu_icon_mng" onclick="f_menu()" onblur="f_menu()"></a>
        <div class="main_menu_list_mng" id="main_menu_list_mng" style="display: block;">

            <a class="main_m_link_mng" href=".mpnt=nzmnd">
                <div class="main_m_mng">
                    <i class="fa fa-volume-control-phone"></i>Account Setting
                </div>
            </a>
            <a class="main_m_link_mng" href="new/mpnt=nzmnd">
                <div class="main_m_mng">
                    <i class="fa fa-volume-control-phone"></i>Posts
                </div>
            </a>

            <a class="main_m_link_mng" href="?pmodir=2646&amp;mpnt=nzmnd"><div class="main_m_mng">
                    <i class="fa fa-volume-control-phone"></i>Users</div></a>


            <a class="main_m_link_mng">
                <div class="main_m_mng"><i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i>Admin Users
                </div>
            </a>
            <!-- <div style="position: absolute;z-index: 105;"> -->
            <div id="sub_menu_mng" class="w3-animate-top-menu sub_menu_mng">
                <div><a href="#">sub menu long</a></div>
                <div><a href="?mpnt=test">User Register</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">Sub menu3</a></div>
            </div>
            <!-- </div> -->

            <a class="main_m_link_mng">
                <div class="main_m_mng"><i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i>New Admin
                </div>
            </a>
            <!-- <div style="position: absolute;z-index: 105;"> -->
            <div id="sub_menu_mng" class="w3-animate-top-menu sub_menu_mng">
     <div><a href="#">sub menu long</a></div>
     <div><a href="?mpnt=test">User Register</a></div>
     <div><a href="#">Sub menu3</a></div>
            </div>
            <!-- </div> -->


            <div class="main_m_mng"><a class="main_m_link_mng"><i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i> Admin Users old link</a>
                <div style="position: absolute;z-index: 105;">
                    <div id="sub_menu_mng" class="w3-animate-top-menu sub_menu_mng">
       <div><a href="#">sub menu long</a></div>
       <div><a href="?mpnt=test">User Register</a></div>
       <div><a href="#">Sub menu3</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div style="
    /* float: left; */
    /* display: inline-block; */
    /* width: 73%; */
    padding: 0 10px;
    padding-right: 160px;
    /* margin-right: -150px; */
    background-color: blue;
    /* z-index: -4; */
    top: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
" class="content">
        
<script src="ref/cml_chk.js"></script>
<script src="ref/statlist2.js"></script>
<!--<script src="chk_frm_reg.js" ></script>-->
<input type="hidden" class="prov1" value="6">

<form name="frmreg" method="post" onreset="" onsubmit="return display_err1()" style="
    margin-block-end: 0em;
">

    <input type="hidden" name="pr_reg_form" value="139">


        


            <input type="hidden" name="pr_reg_form" value="139">

            <div style="margin-right:15px">

                <div class="tbl_tr">
                                            <div class="tbl_td">Date (Today):</div>
                                        <div class="tbl_td" align="right"> :::::::   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        <div id="pers_info">
            <div width="100%" border="0" dir="rtl" cellspacing="10px" style="margin-right:15px" class="tbl">
                <div class="tbl_thead">
                <div class="tbl_th" colspan="3">Pers Info
                    <hr>
                    <br></div>
                </div>
                <!--////////////////////////////////////////================================Form main===========================================================================================================/////////////////-->

            <div class="tbl_tr">
                        <div class="tbl_td" width="">Name :</div>
                        <div class="tbl_td" colspan="2"><input name="fname" id="form_text" type="text" onkeypress="return checkContentname(event)" value=""></div>
                    </div> 
                                    <div class="tbl_tr">
                        <div class="tbl_td">Last Name :</div>
                        <div class="tbl_td" colspan="2"><input name="lname" id="form_text" type="text" onkeypress="return checkContentname(event)" value=""></div>
                    </div>

                

                <div class="tbl_tr">
                    <div class="tbl_td" width="">ID :</div>

                    <div class="tbl_td">
                        <input style="margin-left: 50px" onchange="tel_err2()" name="cmli" id="form_text" type="text" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return checknum(event)" onblur="/*check2()*/" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--//===================================================================================-->
                <!--//===================================================================================-->
                <!--//===================================================================================-->
                <!--        if(){-->
                <div class="tbl_tr" style="display: none">
                    <div class="tbl_td">none disp :</div>
                    <div class="tbl_td" colspan="2" title="">
                        <div>
                            <select name="prov" class="province"></select>
                            <select name="city" class="city"></select>

                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--////////////////////////////////////////================================Form main===========================================================================================================/////////////////-->

            <div class="tbl_tr">
                        <div class="tbl_td" width="">Name :</div>
                        <div class="tbl_td" colspan="2"><input name="fname" id="form_text" type="text" onkeypress="return checkContentname(event)" value=""></div>
                    </div> 
                                    <div class="tbl_tr">
                        <div class="tbl_td">Last Name :</div>
                        <div class="tbl_td" colspan="2"><input name="lname" id="form_text" type="text" onkeypress="return checkContentname(event)" value=""></div>
                    </div>

                

                <div class="tbl_tr">
                    <div class="tbl_td" width="">ID :</div>

                    <div class="tbl_td">
                        <input style="margin-left: 50px" onchange="tel_err2()" name="cmli" id="form_text" type="text" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return checknum(event)" onblur="/*check2()*/" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--//===================================================================================-->                <!--////////////////////////////////////////================================Form main===========================================================================================================/////////////////-->

            <div class="tbl_tr">
                        <div class="tbl_td" width="">Name :</div>
                        <div class="tbl_td" colspan="2"><input name="fname" id="form_text" type="text" onkeypress="return checkContentname(event)" value=""></div>
                    </div> 
                                    <div class="tbl_tr">
                        <div class="tbl_td">Last Name :</div>
                        <div class="tbl_td" colspan="2"><input name="lname" id="form_text" type="text" onkeypress="return checkContentname(event)" value=""></div>
                    </div>

                

                <div class="tbl_tr">
                    <div class="tbl_td" width="">ID :</div>

                    <div class="tbl_td">
                        <input style="margin-left: 50px" onchange="tel_err2()" name="cmli" id="form_text" type="text" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return checknum(event)" onblur="/*check2()*/" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--//===================================================================================-->                <!--////////////////////////////////////////================================Form main===========================================================================================================/////////////////-->

            <div class="tbl_tr">
                        <div class="tbl_td" width="">Name :</div>
                        <div class="tbl_td" colspan="2"><input name="fname" id="form_text" type="text" onkeypress="return checkContentname(event)" value=""></div>
                    </div> 
                                    <div class="tbl_tr">
                        <div class="tbl_td">Last Name :</div>
                        <div class="tbl_td" colspan="2"><input name="lname" id="form_text" type="text" onkeypress="return checkContentname(event)" value=""></div>
                    </div>

                

                <div class="tbl_tr">
                    <div class="tbl_td" width="">ID :</div>

                    <div class="tbl_td">
                        <input style="margin-left: 50px" onchange="tel_err2()" name="cmli" id="form_text" type="text" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return checknum(event)" onblur="/*check2()*/" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--//===================================================================================-->
                </div>



                <!--//===================================================================================-->
                <!--//===================================================================================-->
                <!--//===================================================================================-->

                <!--        -->
                <!--        //================================================================================-->
                <!--        //================================================================================-->
                <!--        //================================================================================-->


            </div>
      </div>
      
<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text<br>test text



<br>
<br>
</form>    


</div>

</div>

    <div class="spacer_ftr" style="height: 150px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    footer
</div>
```

Comment: I use `.spacer_ftr` to have sticky footer in bottom of page and cant remove that

Comment: It's unclear to me why the `.spacer_ftr` would be needed for a sticky footer, but did my suggestion bring you any closer to your solution? 
If so, you could explain in more detail what's the still remaining problem with my solution, I could try to edit my answer to address it.

Comment: I need to remain `.spacer_ftr` and the blue body expand to the bottom but here just fill to end of the form not to the bottom...

Comment: I edited my answere, so that the blue area also expands to the `.spacer_ftr`. Is this what you were searching for?

Answer (score 0):

You must use:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I used this since start this project

Comment: @sidoco what do u mean by u 'used it since started project'?

Comment: I use margin =:0 for body, always

Comment: is that supposed to have `margin = 0` not `margin =:0`

Comment: Excuse me, I have a mistake in typing, `margin : 0` in css :)